# How does Meteor.js detect changes in MongoDB or Mysql?

Tags: meteor

How does Meteor.js detect changes in MongoDB or Mysql? Does it add triggers, or does it poll for changes? If if polls for changes then this seems a rather expensive operation

### Update

I also found an explanation on the Meteor site after some more digging around:

https://www.meteor.com/livequery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MongoDB, Meteor tails the *operation log* (oplog) for changes. In production, this requires the database to be set up as a replica set (a one-member replica set is fine); if it isn't then it will fall back to polling. In development mode, oplog tailing is enabled by default. For more information, see [this (slightly out-of-date) wiki page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver).

There's no native MySQL support in Meteor. There are packages which add MySQL support, but you'll have to read those packages' documentation to see if it uses triggers or polling.